# Как добавить проверку чтобы , рисовался только тот объект который имеет поле заданное пользователем (аргумент)?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hook

Есть метод:

```js
const getAllWaysOfChosenCity = async() => {
  await database.ref("data").on("value", (snapshot) => {
    snapshot.forEach((snap) => {
      setlistOfDataRequest((prevValue) => [...prevValue, snap.val()]);
    });
  });
};
```

При помощи этого метода  я рисую по клику

```html
<div className="result">
  <button className="result__button" onClick={getAllWaysOfChosenCity}>Render Cities </button> {listOfDataRequest.map((city , index) => (
  <tr key={index}>
    <td>{city.amountOfPlaces}</td>
    <td>{city.costOfTrip}</td>
    <td>{city.endBusTrip}</td>
    <td>{city.nameOfBus}</td>
    <td>{city.numberOfBus}</td>
    <td>{city.numberOfWay}</td>
    <td>{city.sequenceOfStops}</td>
    <td>{city.startBusTrip}</td>
  </tr>
  ))}
</div>
```

Нужно в методе getAllWaysOfChosenCity добавить проверку на поле города  чтобы , рисовался только тот объект, который  имеет поле заданное пользователем (аргумент).Например поле startBusTrip === 'Odessa'

Вот ссылка на песочницу (https://codesandbox.io/s/trusting-platform-27c4f)

Answer (score 0):

```
const getAllWaysOfChosenCity = async() => {
      await database.ref("data").on("value", (snapshot) => {
        snapshot.forEach((snap) => {
          if(snap.val().startBusTrip === 'Tumen') {
            console.log(snap.val())
            setlistOfDataRequest((prevValue) => [...prevValue, snap.val()])
          }
        });
      });
    };
```